# What is the proper way to organize a PIP package?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 4 files: `main.py, helper.py, clf.pkl, and tests.py.`

`Main.py` has core classes. It needs to import `helper.py` for some methods and `clf.pkl` for data.

What is the minimal structure I can have for a Python library with 4 files?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to hold your files, along with a `pyproject.toml` to describe your project, like this:

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── your_package_name
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── helper.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── tests.py
```

In your `__init__.py` file write at least:

```
"""A short description of your project"""
__version__ = "0.0.1"
```

(Change description and version accordingly).

To create your `pyproject.toml` you can use `flit init`:

```
pip install flit
flit init
```

Name your entry point `__main__.py` in the package so you can run it using:

```
python -m your_package_name
```

(Yes it's still a good idea to use an `if __name__ == "__main__":` in it, so you can import your **main** from your tests if needed).

You can import `helper.py` from `__main__.py` using:

```
from your_package_name import helper
```

or:

```
from . import helper
```

(I prefer the first one but I don't know if there a concensus.)

For your `clf.pkl` to be included in your package you'll need to create a `MANIFEST.in` with:

```
include your_package_name/clf.pkl
```

Your pkl will be available at:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "clf.pkl")
```

To test it use `flit install -s` and to publish it on PyPI `flit publish`.

Comment: To clarify, main.py is not a script. It is a file containing the core classes. What you are saying still holds, right?

Comment: Can you explain what I write for the entry point thing in flit? The docuentation says: 
"
[tool.flit.entrypoints."pygments.lexers"]
dogelang = "dogelang.lexer:DogeLexer"
" but I don't really get this

https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html

Comment: I also cannot import helper from the main file. I keep getting errors: ImportError: No module named `package_name`

Comment: How are you running your script? Use `python -m package_name` not `python package_name/main.py`.